# C++ - passing data to struct

Tags: c++, function, struct, fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm translating a Fortran 77 code to C++ and the Fortran 77 uses common blocks. I am trying to replace the common blocks with structs which I will then fill with values from a function and then call both to be used in my main. At the moment my code looks like:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// data_list 
struct data_list {
    double g, dw, Vel, M, dt, N;
    int Ioutp1, Ioutp2; 
    } values;

void data (data_list& val) {
    val.g = 9.80665;
    val.dw = 0.05; 
    val.Vel = 20.0;
    val.M = 128; 
    val.dt = 0.05; 
    val.N = 4000;
    val.Ioutp1 = 1;
    val.Ioutp2 = 1;
    }   

void Pierson_Moskowitz(data_list& val) {

/*
* Calculation of properties of Pierson_Moskowitz Spectrum
*/
    double Ug, Hs, A, B, Std;
    cout << values.Vel << "\t\t" << values.g; 
    Ug = values.Vel/values.g;
    cout << Ug << endl;

}   
int main() {
  data(values);
  //float dw = values.dw = 0.05;
  cout << values.dw << endl; 

}
```

This is just a test as at the moment my main isn't doing anything except printing a value. What I want is for the variables that are given values in my `data` function to be able to be used throughout the code. At the moment, there are two things I'm confused about:

1) My `Pierson-Moskowitz` function isn't printing anything for Ug. I don't understand why not?
2) I'm not sure that I even need the `data` function. Essentially the Fortran code that I'm translating uses a subroutine to assign values to variables in a common block. I am trying to do something similar by using a struct and then a function to fill it with values.

This code is quite short and I plan to keep everything in one file. Any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: You're passing your `data_list` by value. None of the changes are making it into the original `values`.

Comment: C++ is pass by value, so the `data` function has its own copy of the `vlaues` object.

Comment: Ok but how would I fix this? I want to be able to access the values given in my void data function.. what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: @user3460758 _"Ok but how would I fix this?"_ `void data (data_list& val)` note the `&`

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass in a reference to your common block:

```
void data (data_list& val) {
```

then you're changes will be to *the* common block rather than a copy.

Comment: Whoops.  Just wrote out a whole answer thinking it was supposed to be C instead of C++...  This one's better!

Comment: Ok this works! Just to clarify though (pretty new to programming still)-- will this change the value to whatever I put in there throughout the whole code? So that if I call the struct again in another function or somewhere else it will always have the values that I gave it in my data function?

Comment: @user3460758 It will change the values of the object you pass to the function. And you can't *call* this struct. It isn't callable.

Comment: @user3460758 yes, simply put `extern data_list values;` in any other compilation unit from which you want to access/change these values.  If you don't need to change use `extern const data_list values;` If this worked for you please give "correct answer".

Comment: So if I include  `extern data_list values` in my main I can access the individual values put in the data function? I'm just trying to work out what the point of doing it the way I'm doing it is or if there is any purpose.

Comment: @user3460758 no, `main` is in your current compilation unit.  In C++ a compilation unit is usually a `.cpp` file you compile to a `.o` object file.  These object files are then linked to your `main` object file to build an executable.  Currently you don't have this extra complication because you just posted your `main` file that could be compiled/linked on it's own.  But I imagine things will get bigger and that's when you'll need seperate compilation units.